# Problema com posicionamento de div - CSS

Tags: css, div

Estou desenvolvendo um hotsite e estou com problemas no css.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu deixo o botão sempre ao lado do texto?

```css
.divFixa{
 font-family: 'Open Sans regular', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 11pt;
 color: #4D4D4D;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 z-index: 99999999;
 right: 0.5%;
 margin-top: 35%;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 0.8%;
 font-size: 9pt;
}
.divFixa a{
 color: white;
 font-size: 9pt;
}
.divFixa a:hover{
 color: white;
}
.botaoFixo {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ED1C24;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-family: 'Open Sans extrabold', sans-serif;
}
.botaoFixo:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #c9040b;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="divFixa">
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    Ligue de qualquer lugar do Brasil
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
  <a class="btn botaoFixo btn-alert" href="tel:">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;numero telefone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
  </div>
<div style="margin-top: 2%;">
  WhatsApp para qualquer lugar do Brasil
</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <a class="btn botaoFixo btn-alert" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=">numero whatsapp </a> 
</div>
Atendemos em mais de <b>150 cidades</b> dos estados de<br /><b>SP, RJ, MG, PR, PE, PO e no DF.</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc quer algo assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqkmS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão para deixar alinhado:

```css
.divFixa{
 font-family: 'Open Sans regular', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 11pt;
 color: #4D4D4D;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 z-index: 99999999;
/* right: 0.5%;
 margin-top: 35%; */
 position: fixed;
 padding: 0.8%;
 font-size: 9pt;
   padding: 15px 5px 15px 15px;

}
.divFixa a{
 color: white;
 font-size: 9pt;
}

.divFixa p{
   float: left;
}

.divFixa a:hover{
 color: white;
}
.botaoFixo {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ED1C24;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-family: 'Open Sans extrabold', sans-serif;
    
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    float: right;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.botaoFixo:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #c9040b;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="divFixa">
   <div>
      <p>Ligue de qualquer lugar do Brasil</p>
      <a class="btn botaoFixo btn-alert" href="tel:">numero telefone</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <p>WhatsApp para qualquer lugar do Brasil</p>
      <a class="btn botaoFixo btn-alert" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=">numero whatsapp</a>
   </div>
   <p>Atendemos em mais de <b>150 cidades</b> dos estados de<br /><b>SP, RJ, MG, PR, PE, PO e no DF.</b></p>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado!!! era exatamente isso

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Comece reestruturando:

*Coloque o texto e o botão dentro do mesmo agrupamento:

```
<style>
 .list_box{
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
 }
.list_box li{
   display:inline-block;
 }
.list_box .left_side{
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
 }
.list_box .right_side{
   display:inline-block;
   float:right;
 }
 </style>

  <div class="list_box">
  <li class="left_side">
  Ligue de qualquer lugar do Brasil
  </li>
  <li class="right_side">
  <a class="btn botaoFixo btn-alert" href="tel:">Tel</a>
  </li>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está colocando uma div para o botão, tente deixando na mesma div do texto.

```
    <div class="divFixa">

    <div style="text-align: left;">
        Ligue de qualquer lugar do Brasil
        <a class="btn botaoFixo btn-alert" href="tel:">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Número Telefone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 2%;">
        WhatsApp para qualquer lugar do Brasil
        <a class="btn botaoFixo btn-alert" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=">Número WhatsApp </a> 
    </div>

    Atendemos em mais de <b>150 cidades</b> dos estados de<br /><b>SP, RJ, MG, PR, PE, PO e no DF.</b>
    </div>
```

Comment: mas aí não funciona o text-align como eu quero